# Why aren't all of my positive values green and negitives red?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am developing a commodities quotes widget. I have setup the 'Current' div and the '24-hour' div, and at one point, all of the positive values were green and the negatives red, but now that's not happening, and as many times as I've gone through my scripting, I can't find the problem.

Here it is in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thetuneupguy/r2Bca/17/

```
var chngClass = '';
var chnginpercentClass = '';
(obj.Change.substr(0,1) == '+') ? chngClass = 'green' : chngClass = 'red';
(obj.Change.substr(0,1) == '+') ? chnginpercentClass = 'green' : chnginpercentClass = 'red';
$lc.append($('<td class="'+chngClass+'">').text(rndchange || "--"));
$lc.append($('<td class="'+chnginpercentClass+'">').text(rndchpercent || "--"));
   });
```

Comment: Please don't make questions that depend on a JSFiddle link to be answerable. You need to include everything *in the question*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have a syntax error in your style sheet:

```
//These two classes, .red & .green are used to change the font color of values
//depending on the symbol that preceeds the value (+ or -)
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

That isn't how you write comments in CSS. You need `/* */`, not `//`. The syntax error nullifies the rule after it, `.red`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/r2Bca/18/